# unwrap optional value nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I am new in ios developer.I pass my data to one view controller to another using function

```
var vc = MessageViewController()
            vc.printSomething(address: address,id: id)
```

I pass address and id to MessageViewController.In MessageViewController

```
func printSomething(address: String,id: String) {    
      print("address",address)
      print("id",id)     
      address_text.text = "\(address)"
}
```

Above code I print address,id but when  i set address on `UITextField` **address.text** I got unwrapping error.

Comment: `MessageViewController()` - that is not how you instantiate ViewControllers. Load them with a nib file or let a Storyboard instantiate it for you.

Comment: @luk2302 You can initiate view controller with `MessageViewController()`, no? But most of the time a `UIViewController` has a .xib or a storyboard with plenty of IBOutlet in Interface Builder. When you do `MessageViewController()`, you just init an `MessageViewController` object, but the init is not linked with the xib/storyboard so IBOutlets are nil.

Comment: @Larme yes, you _can_, but i am lets say 99% sure OP did not want to have an empty view controller where the outlets are nil.

Answer (score 0):

I used to create a class method to instantiate view controller from storyboard like this...

```
class MessageViewController: UIViewController {


 //other methods

  //MARK:- Class Method

  class func viewController() -> MessageViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "<Storyboard Id>") as! MessageViewController
   }


}
```

You need to just use to instantiate view controller

```
var vc = MessageViewController.viewController()
```

You can set storyboard identifier like in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is the issue with variable not assigned to **address_text** beacuse xib not initialized at that time of your method(**printSomething**) calling, before that take two varibles for saving the address and id in MessageViewController and assign id and address to those variables in **printSomething** method and you can assing those values to **address_text** in **viewdidload** method of **MessageViewController**